# How to modify iso that boots bios only to dual boot mode - no EFI files in iso

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, iso

I have been asked to modify a custom built iso, based on Ubuntu 18.04. It currently only boots on Bios and has no EFI related files. How do I generate the required files such as efi.img, BOOTx64.efi, isohdpfx.bin, etc. Can I use the files from the base Ubuntu 18.04?

TIA,
Larry

EDIT: I chroot'ed the iso and found both the BOOT and EFI folders which are not in the built iso. Copied both to the extracted iso. Now the only file I don't have is isohdpfx.bin, which is needed for the xorriso build script.

Comment: If you use the original software `mkisofs, there is a section about multiple boots in the man page. The source is at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

Answer (score 2):

That .bin belongs to syslinux; you might be better off reading through [Rod's books on EFI bootloaders](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) to understand what you're doing in the first place, and maybe enjoying [ISO9660 based UEFI boot picture](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html) in particular.

*PS: this question seems to be a further development on your problem described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560682/); I've written a more elaborate reply there with no further communication from you.  I'm in no case a moderator or staff member here but it's generally a bad thing to spread communications over unconnected questions and not talk back whether any particular advice helped or not -- it's not a technical support line with tickets you file but rather a community, your feedback is important to those who might stumble upon those answers later on.  Duplicating questions is even worse a thing, just like spam; please try and avoid that.*