# Add UEFI boot capability to a BIOS only Ubuntu 18.04 based custom iso

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, iso, mkisofs

I am trying to add UEFI boot capability to a BIOS only Ubuntu 18.04 based custom iso. All the methods I've found so far require an efi.img file which isn't present in the iso. Can I use the file out of a full install Ubuntu 18.04? If yes, do I need to edit it? If not, how can I construct an efi.img file?

The custom iso is designed to run from a USB, not installed. It is also intended for distribution to new Linux users. Adding UEFI capabilities to the USB rather than the iso isn't the solution we're looking for.

This is the script that I used to build the fat partition. It is run in the folder containing the extracted iso:

```
#! /bin/sh

BOOT_IMG_DATA="$PWD"
BOOT_IMG=efi.img

#Ensure needed folders exist

if [ ! -d "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/efi/boot ]; then
  mkdir -p "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/efi/boot
fi

if [ ! -d "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/boot/grub ]; then
  mkdir -p "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/boot/grub
fi

chmod -R +rw "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/boot/grub
chmod -R +rw "$BOOT_IMG_DATA"/efi/boot

# Create the 64-bit EFI GRUB binary (bootx64.efi) and the El-Torito boot
# image (efiboot.img) that goes in the /isolinux directory for booting on
# UEFI systems.

# First, build bootx64.efi, which will be installed here in /EFI/BOOT:

grub-mkimage --format=x86_64-efi --output=bootx64.efi --config=grub.cfg --compression=xz --prefix=/EFI/BOOT part_gpt part_msdos fat ext2 hfs hfsplus iso9660 udf ufs1 ufs2 zfs chain linux boot appleldr ahci configfile normal regexp minicmd reboot halt search search_fs_file search_fs_uuid search_label gfxterm gfxmenu efi_gop efi_uga all_video loadbios gzio echo true probe loadenv bitmap_scale font cat help ls png jpeg tga test at_keyboard usb_keyboard

# Then, create a FAT formatted image that contains bootx64.efi in the
# /EFI/BOOT directory.  This is used to bootstrap GRUB from the ISO image.
dd if=/dev/zero of=efiboot.img bs=1K count=1440

# Format the image as FAT12:
mkdosfs -F 12 efiboot.img

# Create a temporary mount point:
MOUNTPOINT=$(mktemp -d)

# Mount the image there:
mount -o loop efiboot.img $MOUNTPOINT

# Copy the GRUB binary to /EFI/BOOT:
mkdir -p $MOUNTPOINT/EFI/BOOT
cp -a bootx64.efi -s $MOUNTPOINT/EFI/BOOT


# Unmount and clean up:
umount $MOUNTPOINT
rmdir $MOUNTPOINT

# Move the efiboot.img to isolinux:
mv efiboot.img isolinux
mv bootx64.efi efi/boot

echo
echo "Done building /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi and /isolinux/efiboot.img."
```

This is the script I use to build the iso:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The example names get mapped to their roles here
orig_iso="$HOME"/foxclone/foxclone025-01.iso
new_iso="$HOME"/foxclone/foxclone025-02.iso
new_files="$PWD"
mbr_template=isohdpfx.bin


# Extract MBR template file to disk
dd if="$orig_iso" bs=1 count=432 of="$mbr_template"


# Create the new ISO image
xorriso -as mkisofs \
   -U  \
   -allow-lowercase  \
   -r -V 'foxclone025-02' \
   -o "$new_iso" \
   -J -J -joliet-long \
   -isohybrid-mbr "$mbr_template" \
   -c isolinux/boot.cat \
   -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
   -eltorito-alt-boot \
   -e isolinux/efiboot.img \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
   "$new_files"
```

Does anyone see a problem in the code? I really appreciate a different set of eyes looking at this as I think I've gotten "too close to the forest to see the trees".

TIA, Larry

Comment: This is a complete duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560242/

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202371/add-uefi-boot-capability-to-a-bios-only-ubuntu-18-04-based-custom-iso You need /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and whatever else that needs to boot. UEFI only boots external devices from bootx64.efi.

Comment: `mkisofs` includes the option `-eltorito-platform efi` for this purpose. See http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html for more information.

Comment: Solved - I had a couple of files from the wrong version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is w xooriso. Try this, extract a boot sector from a normal live iso first, as describe here:

https://linuxconfig.org/legacy-bios-uefi-and-secureboot-ready-ubuntu-live-image-customization

Interesting that the files arent there.
syslinux-utils package has isohybrid. dunno y it got moved. dont care.

The formentioned way, works. Otherwise the utils will only make a i386/i686 version by default.

uck can be modded to use udf and limited-size, to get dvdDL and BDR images made that work.

xorriso works but is outside of spec for sizes above ~4GB.

squishfs exceeds the limit most of the time. more particularly the file size limit of 4GB, not iso size limit. If you dont specifiy allow limited joliet/rr size, most utils fail at iso creation. Alternative is to build an install only iso, like debian does. not without its other fair share of issues. Ive not yet exceeded bootable bdrom sizes,specs, even w heavyweight gamer distro spun(fedora).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).